# Kotlin - How to check double in if condition

Tags: kotlin

I have if statment and I wanted to check my variable if is double.

Here is my code:

```
val doubleVal = (findViewId<EditText>(R.id.)).text.toString()
val doubleS = Double.parseDouble(doubleVal)

if(???)
{
    println("Number is double")
}
else
{
    editDouble.error = "Type double number!!"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [`toDoubleOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html) available which:

> Parses the string as a `Double` number and returns the result or null if
>   the string is not a valid representation of a number.

You can use it like so:

```
val maybeDouble = kmValue.toDoubleOrNull()
if (maybeDouble != null) {
  println("Number is double")
} else {
  editDouble.error = "Type double number!!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by miensol, `toDoubleOrNull` is a great tool for solving your problem. I’d like to add that Kotlin provides a [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) function that can help to write idiomatic code when handling nullable types like the resulting `Double?`:

```
val maybeDouble = "1.2".toDoubleOrNull()
maybeDouble?.let {
    println("Number is double")
} ?: println("Type double number!!")
```